# C#:DateTime.Now Month output format

Tags: c#

In this C# code snippet, `DateTime.Now.Month.ToString()` returns `7` as output.

I would like to get `07` as a return value.

What can I do to add the leading zero when the month has only 1 digit?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("d2")
```

Answer (score 56):

Either format the integer with two digits as suggested by Mehrdad, or format the `DateTime` itself to give you a two-digit month:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM")
```

Answer (score 27):

I'm using Selenium Webdriver to test a website and set various vars, strings, etc. at the beginning; this made it a lot simpler:

```
/* Date strings */
public static string TodayNum = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");        // e.g 07
public static string ThisMonthNum = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");    // e.g 03
public static string ThisMonthShort = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM");  // e.g Mar
public static string ThisMonthLong = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");  // e.g March
public static string ThisYearNum = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");   // e.g 2014
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question, even after I removed the fluff.

Answer (score 7):

You can also convert Month and Day to two digit number by following functions too:

```
System.DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("00") //Give 01 for January
System.DateTime.Now.Day.ToString("00")
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use: `DateTime.Now.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');`

It will return: `07`