# how to add zero to day and month in my code?

Tags: c#, xaml

I search a lot about date time string format to add zero to my day and month.
but all of them in console application and the others not what I expected.
please guide me to how fix my codes.

```
    private string NowDate()
    {
        PersianCalendar persiancalnder = new PersianCalendar();
        DateTime timenow = DateTime.Now;
        int day = persiancalnder.GetDayOfMonth(timenow);
        int month = persiancalnder.GetMonth(timenow);
        int year = persiancalnder.GetYear(timenow);
        string result = year.ToString() + "/" + month.ToString() + "/" + day.ToString();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152583/cdatetime-now-month-output-format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `string.PadLeft()`:

```
string result = year.ToString() + "/" + month.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0') + "/" + day.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0');
```

this is even more readable:

```
string result = $"{year}/{month.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0')}/{day.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0')}";
```

Comment: can you explain about different between your codes please ?

Comment: no difference at all, only the second one is cleaner, but it works in c# 6+

Answer (score 0):

According to [that manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros):

```
string result = $"{year}/{month:D2}/{day:D2}";
```